# How to validate a random graph's chromatic number

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I developed an algorithm that can calculate the chromatic number of a graph with n vertices in roughly n^2 time. I verified that this works for smaller graphs, but I am looking for a systematic way to verify that this works for larger, more complex graphs. Is there an existing, systematic way to determine chromatic number that I could use to validate my answers?

Comment: Computing the chromatic number is NP-hard.  In essence, it means that no one knows of a polynomial time algorithm to compute it.  With the current knowledge, your best hope is an exponential time algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

If this were really true, it would be **big** news, but it's almost certainly not.
Graph colouring is well-known to be NP-complete, so if you really have a polynomial-time algorithm (and can prove that!) you have proved that P=NP.  You can then apply for your million dollar Millenium Prize from the Clay Mathematics Institute.

But, as I said, it's almost certainly not true.

As for your question, you can find some challenging graph-colouring benchmarks at the Google [Graph Coloring Benchmarks](https://sites.google.com/site/graphcoloring/home) site.

Comment: Much appreciated. I realize that this is an NP-complete problem, which is why I'm expecting things fall apart with more complex test cases. I've just been struggling to find resources with such test cases that also include a reference solution.